# How to read the first column data from CSV file and compare it with user input?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, csv

I am developing an app where users can upload a csv file to documents folder of app (I finished it). But I want to give a textfield to users in the app and ask them to enter a id number and this number will be checked with the uploaded csv files first column. If it matches then display an alert saying that its found a match or else it doesn't.

Comment: Ya.. I did. But no results came there for comparision.

Comment: What do you mean by comparison? IS this ID in the first column of the CSV file? If so, your just comparing two strings for equality?

Comment: my csv file will be having each row in the format of "g1, name, address". There wont be row numbers. So if the user types g1 in the text box, I should search the csv file and tell the user that I found it. It has to look through the whole CSV file's first column to find a match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe csv files are text files with comma separated columns and newline (\n) separated rows. So one way to search every row's first column element would be to use NSString's method componentsSeparatedByString:.

EDIT: Load csv file into NSString instance.

```
NSString * pstrCSVFilePath= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"CSVFile" ofType:@""]
NSString * pstrCSVFile= [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pstrCSVFilePath encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:NULL];

NSArray * paRowsOfCSVFile= [pstrCSVFile componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
NSArray * paColumnsOfRow;
NSString * pstrFirstColumn;
for(NSString * pstrRow in paRowsOfCSVFile)
{
    paColumnsOfRow= [pstrRow componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    pstrFirstColumn= [paColumnsOfRow objectAtIndex:0];
    if([pstrFirstColumn localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:myTextField.text] == NSOrderedSame)
    {
         //Found the search string in the CSV file. 
         break;
    }
}
```

Comment: May I know what is pstrCSVFile here?

Comment: I added some code in an EDIT above. I'm assuming your CSV file is stored in the app's bundle. One way or the other you want to get the entire contents of the CSV file read into an NSString.

Comment: I want to store the CSV in App Documents (since its easier to upload csv file to the app though iTunes). So the if condition should be like if([pstrFirstColumn localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:pstrSearchString] == myTextFied.text) 
    { //code } ?

Comment: I'm not sure what your asking.

Comment: sorry... Lets say if the user types g1 in UITextField called mytext. So the comparison if condition's argument is ([pstrFirstColumn localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:pstrSearchString] == myTextFied.text)  right?

Comment: Ah, no. [pstrFirstColumn localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:myTextFied.text] == NSOrderedSame

Comment: Thanks Mark. Greatly appreicate it.

Comment: Hello Mark, I just have quick question. Your code works perfectly. So when I find the record I want to add extra column at the end of the row saying "found". I would greatly appreciate your help in this.